# how to get variable name on loop javascript, and variable type is array

Tags: javascript

this is my varibale in js

```
    var schemapost = {};
    var schemacrumb = {};
    var og = {};
    var meta = {};

    $.get('json', function(resp) {
        schemapost = {
            "@context":"http://schema.org",
            "@type":"Article",
            "mainEntityOfPage":permalink,
            "headline":title,
            "description":description
        };

        schemacrumb = {
            "@context":"http://schema.org",
            "@type":"BreadcrumbList",
        };

        og = {
            "fb:app_id":resp.facebook_app_id,
            "fb:admins":resp.facebook_id,
        };

        meta = {
            "description":description,
            "keywords":post_keyword,
            "robots":"noodp"
        };
    });
```

so i collect all variable in one variable which is

```
    var schema = [schemapost,schemacrumb,og,meta];
```

and i try to loop that variable and got confused

```
foreach ( a in schema ){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/make_schema.php",
        data: { data : JSON.stringify(???EACH VARIABLE NAME??), 
                post_name : slug , 
                variablename : ???EACH VARIABLE NAME?? },
    });
}
```

obviously stupid but i try this:

```
var schema = ["schemapost","schemacrumb","og","meta"];

schema.forEach(function(entry) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/kode/post/make_json",
        data: {value : JSON.stringify(entry), post_name:slug, variablename:entry},
    });
});
```

and output is string.. not variable array data like i want,
any suggestion how to loop array variable and get each variable name so i can use for data:variablename in ajax function?

Comment: why do you want to make multiple post requests for the objects in array ?

Comment: i try to auto make json file in one click, so i can use for structure data in my website.

Comment: so you want to send the complete json structure of schema  via post method to backend ?

Comment: yes.. as far as i know about web programing so i try to make json file, then i can call it inside my codegniter controller.. is that right thing to do?? please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the complete schema array that you have created,

```
var schema = [schemapost,schemacrumb,og,meta];
```

using Jquery post method as :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/make_schema.php",
    data: { data : schema , 
            post_name : slug
});
```

and catch the complete array in backend process as array

Comment: ok.. do i have create file or just make dynamic in my controller, thanks for suggestion..